# Postgresql is not getting data from CRUD form

Tags: python, html, django, postgresql

I am new to PostgreSQL and I have been making a CRUD code using django,python,html,and PostgreSQL

here's my code
templates\employee_register\base.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Employee Register</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
        integrity="sha384-zCbKRCUGaJDkqS1kPbPd7TveP5iyJE0EjAuZQTgFLD2ylzuqKfdKlfG/eSrtxUkn" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery@3.5.1/dist/jquery.slim.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.1/dist/umd/popper.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-9/reFTGAW83EW2RDu2S0VKaIzap3H66lZH81PoYlFhbGU+6BZp6G7niu735Sk7lN"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.1/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-VHvPCCyXqtD5DqJeNxl2dtTyhF78xXNXdkwX1CZeRusQfRKp+tA7hAShOK/B/fQ2"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.1.1/css/all.min.css">
</head>

<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="col-md-10 offset-md-1 mt-5">
            <div class="jumbotron">
                <h1 class="display-4">Employee Register</h1>
                <p class="lead-front-italic">python django project for crud implementation</p>
                <hr class="my-4">
                {% block content %}
                {% endblock content %}
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>

</body>

</html>
```

employee_form.html

```
{% extends "employee_register/base.html" %}
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}
{% block content %}
<form action="" method="post" autocomplete="off">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{form.first_name|as_crispy_field}}
    {{form.middle_name|as_crispy_field}}
    {{form.last_name|as_crispy_field}}
    <!-- <div class="row"> -->
        <!-- <div class="col-md-4"> -->
            {{form.emp_code|as_crispy_field}}
        <!-- </div> -->
        <!-- <div class="col-md-8"> -->
            {{form.department|as_crispy_field}}
            {{form.designation|as_crispy_field}}
            {{form.location|as_crispy_field}}
            {{form.status|as_crispy_field}}
            {{form.date_of_birth|as_crispy_field}}
            {{form.date_of_joining|as_crispy_field}}
            {{form.gender|as_crispy_field}}
        <!-- </div> -->
    <!-- </div> -->
     <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">
        <i class="fa-solid fa-database"></i>Submit
     </button>
</form>
{% endblock content %}
```

employee_register.html

```
{% extends "employee_register/base.html" %}

{% block content %}
<p>we'll show list of employee from the table</p>
{% endblock content %}
```

models.py

```
from django.db import models

class Position(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=50)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

# Create your models here.
class Employee(models.Model):
    first_name=models.CharField(max_length=100)
    middle_name=models.CharField(max_length=100)
    last_name=models.CharField(max_length=100)
    emp_code=models.CharField(max_length=3)
    department=models.CharField(max_length=100)
    designation=models.ForeignKey(Position,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    location = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    date_of_birth=models.DateField()
    date_of_joining=models.DateField()
    gender = models.CharField(max_length=6)
    status = models.CharField(max_length=10)
```

```
from django.shortcuts import render,redirect
from .forms import EmployeeForm
# Create your views here.
def employee_list(request):
    return render(request,"employee_register/employee_list.html")

def employee_form(request):
    if request.method == "GET":
        form = EmployeeForm()
        return render(request,"employee_register/employee_form.html",{'form':form})

    else:
        form = EmployeeForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
        return redirect('/employee/list')
```

after I submit my information in form
it doesn't appear in the table of PostgreSQL

whats the solution to deal with this problem?

Comment: do you have any log or error message ?
and what is your EmployeeForm code ?

Comment: I'm just guessing that your problem is somewhere in your `EmployeeForm.save` function but we didn't get to see that, can you edit that in?

Comment: Can you show the db configured in settings.py

Comment: ```from django.shortcuts import render,redirect
from .forms import EmployeeForm
def employee_list(request):
    return render(request,"employee_register/employee_list.html")

def employee_form(request):
    if request.method == "GET":
        form = EmployeeForm()
        return render(request,"employee_register/employee_form.html",{'form':form})

    else:
        form = EmployeeForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
        return redirect('/employee/list')

Comment: Could you add your code where your `EmployeeForm` class is declared?  Also, where you have `if form.is_valid():` you should put an `else` condition that prints errors, such as `print(form.errors)`.  That might show the issue.